# Pandas Сравнение двух разных датафреймов с промежуточной группировкой

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Есть два датафрейма:

| day | code | name | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | qwe | 1 |
| 1 | 001 | ewq | 2 |
| 2 | 002 | qaz | 5 |
| 3 | 003 | zyx | 6 |

| day | code | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 3 |
| 3 | 003 | 6 |
| 4 | 002 | 5 |
| 6 | 001 | 7 |

если данные в колонках day и code совпадают в обеих таблицах, то проверяем на совпадения колонку qty, если количество совпадает, то создаем третий датафрейм, куда переносим совпадающие колонки из первого.
вид третьего датафрейма:

| day | code | name | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | qwe | 1 |
| 1 | 001 | ewq | 2 |
| 3 | 003 | zyx | 6 |

я пытался решить через GroupBy, сгруппировав первый датафрейм, но не понимаю, как после сравнения и совпадения вернуть колонки к изначальному виду с сохранением количества и имяни.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"day"  : ["1", "1", "2","3"],
                   "code" : ["001","001","002","003"],
                   "name" : ["qwe","ewq","qaz","zyx"],
                   "qty"  : ["1","2","5","6"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"day"  : ["1", "4","3","6"],
                   "code" : ["001","002","003","001"],
                    "qty"  : ["3","5","6","7"]})
```

Comment: Не могли бы пояснить, что значит "количество совпадает"?

Comment: @strawdog
в указаном примере, если я сгруппирую DF1 по day и code, то в первой строке DF1["qty"] == DF2["qty"] именно это мне и нужно проверить, при условии совпадения, создать DF3 в который перенести совпадающие строки, проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как сохранить колонку name, и оригинальное количество из DF1

Comment: не ясно. в группировки в Df1 получается две строки qty со значением 1 и 2. эти значения в сумме должны равняться значению qty из df2 (3)?

Comment: @strawdog да, именно так, и если, значения равны, то нужно строку из промежуточной группировки вернуть к изначальному состоянию  и перенести в новый DF3

Comment: я дополнил свой ответ, проверьте. сам проверить не могу из-за нерепрезентативности  вашего датафрейма.

Comment: @strawdog благодарю за ответ,  поправил вопрос, в  предложенном Вами решении, вторая, сгруппированная на момент цикла строка не попадает под запись в третий датафрейм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- выносите в индекс во втором датафрейме день и код
- группируете первый датафрейм по дню и коду и суммируете количество
- делаете merge датафреймов
- оставляете записи, где количества совпадают
- выносите в индекс в первом датафрейме день и код
- делаете мерж того что получилось перед этим с этим первым фреймом
- выкидываете лишние колонки

Может можно проще, но навскидку так.

Answer (score 0):

не совсем понял, зачем вам группировка.

попробуйте сделать так, например:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["day", "code"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["day", "code"])
res = df1.join(df2, how='inner', rsuffix="r").iloc[:,:-1].reset_index()
```

res:

```
   day code name  qty 
0    1  001  qwe     1
1    1  001  ewq     2​
```

UPDATE

Если нужно выяснить, соответствует ли сумма qty в группе значению из второго датафрейма, то можно сделать так:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["day", "code"])
df2 = df2.set_index(["day", "code"])
tmp = df1.join(df2, how='inner', lsuffix="l", rsuffix="r").reset_index()

res = pd.DataFrame()
for i, g in tmp.groupby(["day", "code"]):
    if g["qty l"].sum() == g.iloc[0, 4]:
        res = pd.concat((res,g.iloc[:,:-1]))
```

res теперь:

```
   day code name  qty l
0    1  001  qwe      1
1    1  001  ewq      2
```

Comment: Группировка вроде ему нужна чтобы проверить, что количество сошлось. Хотя зачем не знаю

Comment: @CrazyElf точно, про количество я пропустил.

Comment: @CrazyElf  к сожелению информация поступает именно в таком виде, из двух разных источников, нужно сравнить общее количество с тем, что присылают люди, именно поэтому имя и количество обязательные строки для сохранения. я решил эту задачу через openpyXL, но получилось очень громоздко, посоветовали попробовать решить через Pandas.

Comment: @MaxProkopenko Ну вы почитайте схему в моём ответе. Она тоже громоздкая с виду, но там каждый шаг это одна строка кода. Код там не сложно написать, но муторно, может сами напишете?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, конечно, спасибо за ответ, на днях обязательно попробую написать, пользуясь вашей схемой.

Comment: @CrazyElf К сожелению в момент группировки теряются записи из колонки name (запись из первой строки сохраняется, а вот запись из строки, которая группируется с первой пропадает)

Comment: @MaxProkopenko Так для этого второй `merge` потом и нужен, чтобы остальные колонки подтянуть

Comment: @CrazyElf да, я не правильно Вас понял, что для группировки нужно создавать временный DF, все заработало! огоромное спасибо